# Access nested array members

Tags: powershell

I have nested array on Powershell that for some reason can't be able to access in any way.

```
{@{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d}, @{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3}}
```

I have tried this and many other tutorials on Google without any luck:

```
$licenses = {@{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d}, @{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3}}

foreach ($license in $licenses) {
    Write-Host $licenses
    Write-Host $licenses.skuId
}
```

What i'm trying to arhieve is mergin these skuId's to CSV like
`$licenses = "f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d, f245ecc8-75af-4f8e-b61f-27d8114de5f3"`

Comment: How do you get the value in the variable? Please [edit] the question and show actual code.

Comment: Give `$licenses.skuId -join ', '` a try

Comment: `@{disabledPlans=System.Object[]; skuId=f30db892-07e9-47e9-837c-80727f46fd3d}` is not valid syntax, looks more like you copy-pasted a ToString representation of a hashtable.